# Update application via github or others

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello I am wondering if any method to update an application automatically

example: when there is an update it will take you to the website to update the application or update automatically

Is there any way to do this?

(in playstore I can't)

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for CI/CD in github.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called JGit which you can use to pull from git/github repositories. You could write a function to pull automatically using JGit

Comment: can you send me the code? i don't know much java, i'm trying to practice

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide has some resources